# CSS Selectors - First h2 in a table

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm trying to select the first h2 in this table (which is called 'styling') but really struggling. I've tried nth-of-type and first of type.

Could someone show me what I'm doing wrong / edit my fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/SparrwHawk/JxZ6Y/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
table tr:first-child td:first-child h2{font-weight:bold}
```

Comment: just to be safe you should put `h2:first-child`, also, in case the cell has multiple `h2`s

Comment: and if there will be no `h2` in the first row? But in the second one?

Comment: @ZoltanToth it could be modified to `table tr:first-child h2:first-child` - it kind of depends on what you know the setup will be.

Comment: @ThomasShields I know that :) I was just trying to say that this is not a generic solution, but rather a hack for this particular case.

Answer (score 3):

The `:nth-of-type(1)` selector matches every element that is the first child, of a particular type, of its parent. All your h2 are first child of its parent (a td).

If that `<h2>` is different semantically (and so it is surely if you want it to be styled in a different way), you should add a class (`<h2 class="its-semantic">`)to it and select it through the class: `table h2.its-semantic`

Comment: Useful comment about the nth-of-type, but I want to target the first h2 to add a margin, it's not different semantically. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can define a unique ID(#) or a class(.) to that h2

```
<h2 class="target"> Styling </h2>
```

Then you can target it from css:

```
h2.target { color: organge; font-size: 200px;} //You can either use h2.target or .target both works
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SparrwHawk/JxZ6Y/

I edited and made the font size bigger so you can see the difference.

**EDIT : ===============================================================**

Alright, here is the solution using css selectors.

`table tbody tr:nth-child(1) > td h2 { color:grey; font-size: 100px;}`

Add that code of line at the top and it would specifically target only your 1st h2

This is what code says :

Target Table and go to tbody and inside tbody target the 1st tr using the nth-child(1) then target the td and then go to h2

Alternatively you can even do this: 
`table tbody tr:nth-child(1) td:first-child { color:grey; font-size: 100px;}`

The code is pretty much similar to the above code I wrote for you except removing h2 and and first-child property to td.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I already know I can target it with a class, I specifically wanted to do it with selectors so that it's flexible.

Comment: Alright, here is the solution using css selectors.

`table tbody tr:nth-child(1) > td h2 { color:grey; font-size: 100px;}`

Add that code of line at the top and it would specifically target only your 1st h2

This is what code says :

Target Table and go to tbody and inside tbody target the 1st tr using the nth-child(1) then target the td and then go to h2 

Alternatively you can even do this: 
`table tbody tr:nth-child(1) td:first-child { color:grey; font-size: 100px;}`

The code is pretty much similar to the above code I wrote for you except removing h2 and and first-child property to td.

Answer (score 0):

```
table tr:first-child h2 {}
```

That should do it, instead of using the selector on the h2, use it to find the first `<tr>` instead and apply the styles to `<h2>` within that `<tr>`

See the updated jsFiddle :)

http://jsfiddle.net/JxZ6Y/4/

Answer (score 0):

You could select the h2 element in the first tr element of your table

```
table tr:first-child h2
```

I'm assuming you aren't targeting IE8 or earlier because nth-child() is only supported in IE9. :first-child is similarly supported in IE9, and somewhat in IE8. http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html